# Namespace 'cmb1' causes C++ compilation error

Tags: c++, windows, namespaces

When I try to compile this code:

```
#include <windows.h>

namespace cmb1 {
}

void main() {}
```

I get this:

```
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
a.cc
a.cc(3) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
a.cc(3) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
a.cc(3) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Ditto for `cmb2`, `cmb3` and `cmb4`. I stopped at that point. `cm4`, btw, compiles just fine.

I tried surrounding the namespace with something else:

```
namespace dilum {
namespace cmb4 {
}
}
```

But the compile still failed.

What is going on?

Comment: So simple it's not even right! :-)

Comment: Btw,You should not be using `cmb2`, `cmb3`, `cmb4` for an namespace name at all, It does not say anything at all, Maintenance nightmare for people working after really.

Comment: @Dilum: `void main()` is simple, and `int main()` is complex? How exactly?

Comment: Query Google for `+windows.h "cmb1"`

Comment: `void main()` is plainly **Wrong**, Simple or not it is just Wrong. Being simple at expense of being incorrect doesn't make sense.

Comment: Fine. I clearly suck at C++. How is this discussion helping with the question of `cmb1` having strange effects on code?

Comment: @Dilum : Note that no one is mentioning this in an answer -- comments are often used for constructive criticism not directly related to the question at hand. No need to be offended.

Comment: That's fair. However, when someone just says 'wrong' with no explanation as to why, it sounds religious to me. Given that the compiler didn't even produce a warning, what is 'wrong' with a no-op program not returning a value?

Comment: @Dilum : The C++ standard explicitly forbids it (§3.6.1/2); any compiler that allows it (and most do, for legacy reasons) is doing so as an extension, but it is not standard, legal C++.

Comment: @Als -- CMB is a Cash Management Bill in the finance space. `cmb1` is where a bunch of constants for CMB related tests are being placed. In reality, the 'outer' namespaces were `test` and `data` to produce `test::data::cmb1`.

Comment: @ildjarn Ah. That's more educational. Thank you.

Comment: @Dilum: It is incorrect because standard specifically says so, Read  § **3.6.1 ¶ 2:** *It shall have a return type of int,.....*

Comment: Also, and decent compiler should warn you if you enable all warnings, as you most definitely should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from windows.h:

```
#define cmb1 0x470
#define cmb2 0x471
#define cmb3 0x472
#define cmb4 0x473
#define cmb5 0x474
#define cmb6 0x475
#define cmb7 0x476
#define cmb8 0x477
#define cmb9 0x478
#define cmb10 0x479
#define cmb11 0x47A
#define cmb12 0x47B
#define cmb13 0x47C
#define cmb14 0x47D
#define cmb15 0x47E
#define cmb16 0x47F
```

Comment: Hehe, insidious! Is this also active if you have `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`?

Answer (score 3):

`cmb1` may be a macro defined in `windows.h`. If the macro expands itself to an expression, the compiler sees

```
namespace <the_expanded_expression> {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The constant `cmb1` is defined in `<windows.h>` as follows:

```
#define cmb1 0x0470
```

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you can hover over the red squiggly arrow under `cmb1` to see the definition.

Needless to say, `namespace 0x0470 { }` is not a valid namespace declaration.